# How to convert yyyymm(numeric) to mmm-yyyy in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, m

How to convert yyyymm(numeric) to mmm-yyyy in power bi?

Dataset:

```
YRMONTH ABCD  CBDA  BDAC
202101  1234  1234  1233
202102  1233  1233  1234
202103  1234  1234  1234
...
```

Target:

```
YRMONTH  ABCD  CBDA  BDAC
Jan-2021 1234  1234  1233
Fab-2021 1233  1233  1234
Mar-2021 1234  1234  1234
...
```

and Pivot it

```
       Jan-2021  Feb-2021  Mar 2021 ... Till Endofyear
ABCD   1234      1233      1233
CBDA   1234      1233      1234
BDAC   1233      1234      1234
...
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the year and month to turn it into a date and then format it as MMM-yyyy.

The key bit of code is

```
each Date.ToText(#date(Number.IntegerDivide(_, 100), Number.Mod(_, 100), 1), "MMM-yyyy")
```

but here's the full M code you can paste into the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMjQwVNJRMjQyNkGhjJVidaDyRjARZMoEIW+MTT9QPhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [YRMONTH = _t, ABCD = _t, CBDA = _t, BDAC = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"YRMONTH", Int64.Type}, {"ABCD", Int64.Type}, {"CBDA", Int64.Type}, {"BDAC", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Convert Int to Date Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"YRMONTH", each Date.ToText(#date(Number.IntegerDivide(_, 100), Number.Mod(_, 100), 1), "MMM-yyyy"), type date}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Convert Int to Date Text", {"YRMONTH"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Columns", {{"YRMONTH", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Columns", {{"YRMONTH", type text}}, "en-US")[YRMONTH]), "YRMONTH", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```